# Ternary Operator in JavaScript With Multiple Expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

```
the_styles ? the_styles.appendTo('head'); the_styles=null : the_styles = $('.stylesheet').detach();
```

Obviously, this isn't valid. Notice the ";" between the `appendTo()` and `the_styles=null`. How do I write it on 1 line and still have multiple expressions like that?

Comment: Just a piece of advice: the ternary operator in some other languages is not used to write complete statements, but only the expression part (i.e. the part right of the '=' sign). In Java this would fail to compile in the first place. It's better not to make a habit out of this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the comma operator this way:

```
the_styles ? (the_styles.appendTo('head'), the_styles=null) : the_styles =  $('.stylesheet').detach();
```

Here's what the Mozilla Developer Center writes about the comma operator:

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a for loop.
>
> Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: That's a really neat form. I also didn't expect the braces to so profoundly change the meaning of the statement. I don't think I'd write this even by accident, but compare `var x = 1,y=2,z=3;` and `var x = (1,y=2,z=3);`. In the first case, `x` is set to `1`. In the second case, `x` is set to `3`. That's really, really neat.

Answer (score 8):

Who needs the ternary operator?

```
​the_styles = !the_styles && $('.stylesheet').detach()​​​​ ||
             the_styles.appendTo('head') && null;​
```

Had to switch the expressions around as otherwise the `null` value of the first expression will always force the second expression `.detach()` to be evaluated.

The only thing about clever code is that once you come back to it after a coffee break, it won't make any sense even to you. So this is much better:

```
if(the_styles) {
    the_styles.appendTo('head')
    the_styles = null;
}
else {
    the_styles = the_styles.detach('.stylesheet');
}
```

To me, even the above simplistic version doesn't make any sense. The *what* part is obvious, but **why** is it doing that?

Comment: +1 - I had a similar answer, but mis-read the intention. Yours is right.

Comment: @patrick - It took me a while to evaluate the short-circuiting which is always a screaming signal to not try to be clever :)

Answer (score 2):

```
the_styles ? (function() {the_styles.appendTo('head'); the_styles=null})() : <etc>
```

Just wrap the code block in `(function() {`  and `})()`.

Now for the hard part: **why** would you want to do this? Perhaps there's a better solution!

Comment: yeah, thats ugly, nevermind. I just like ternary's because they're clean and a single line is all.

Comment: As long as the code in each branch is a single "line" they're nice. Otherwise... use multiple lines!

Answer (score 1):

i agree with glowcoder but if you still want it:

```
the_styles ? function(){ the_styles.appendTo('head'); the_styles=null;}() : the_styles = $('.stylesheet').detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the_styles ? the_styles.appendTo('head') : the_styles = $('.stylesheet').detach();
```

you dont need to null it if your overwriting it !

Comment: I need the null because if not, it keeps the same value after the initial click and i need an "off/on" function.

Answer (score 0):

```
the_styles=the_styles || $('.stylesheet').detach(); the_styles.appendTo('head');
```