# jquery: is there a concise way to conditionally use a 2nd selector if a 1st selector comes back empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In python, I can do the following, to conditionally use a 2nd list if a 1st one is empty:

```
>>> x = [ ] or [1, 2]
>>> x
[1, 2]
```

In javascript, however,

```
>>> x = [ ] || [1, 2];
[ ]
```

So, if the "or trick" is off the table, I'm wondering whats the most concise way to do something like the following if-javascript-were-python-this-would-work pseudocode:

```
$elems = $('first-selector') || $('second-selector')
```

Comment: You can check the length of the results. Though what is your response if both come back with 0 results?

Comment: hiya, ternary operator might do the trick! var $elem = (foo.length == 0) ? [] : [1,2]; ; or for more read or checkout other articles around ternary if you keen to know more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168136/ternary-operator-in-javascript-with-multiple-expressions hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: Ternary operators: saving a few bytes in characters while creating arcane-looking code since 1950.

Comment: @Greg, nitpicker's corner: [CPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPL_%28programming_language%29) did not exist until the early sixties ;p

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That gets a broad grin from me. Thumbs up! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var elems = $("first-selector");
if(!elems.length) {
    elems = $("second-selector");
}
```

is not concise enough?

How about writing a little jquery extension?

```
$.fn.or = function(selector) {
    if (this.length) {
        return this;
    }

    return $(selector);
}

var elems = $("first-selector").or("second-selector")
```

Comment: Even shorter: `$.fn.or = function(x){ return this.length ? this : $(x) }` :-P

Answer (score 2):

You can base your test off of the length:

```
// Cache your results
var first  = $(".first");
var second = $(".second");

// Assign your results
$elems = !first.length ? second : first;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function coalesceArray(){
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] && arguments[i].length) return arguments[i];
  }
  return [];
}
```

then use `coalesceArray($('first-selector'), $('second-selector'))`